# Evaluate $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\cos x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\cos x, -\infty<x<\infty,t>0\\
> u(x,0)=\sin x,   -\infty<x<\infty\\
> u_t(x,0)=1+x,  -\infty<x<\infty
> \end{cases}
> $$

This is a non-homogeneous, infinite wave equation so we can use d'Alembert's formula

$$u(x,t)=\frac{f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)}{2}+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(s)ds+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-c(t-k)}^{x+c(t-k)}G(s,k)dsdk$$

Where $c=1,f(x)=\sin x, g(x)=1+x,G(t,x)=\cos x$

So

$$u(x,t)=\frac{sin(x+t)+sin(x-t)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(s+\frac{s^2}{2})\big|_{x-t}^{x+t}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}sin(s)\big|_{x-(t-k)}^{x+(t-k)}dk$$

$$u(x,t)=\sin x \cos t+\frac{1}{2}(x+t-(x-t)+\frac{(x+t)^2}{2}-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2})\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}sin({x+(t-k)})-\sin (x-(t-k))dk$$

$$u(x,t)=\sin x \cos t+t+xt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}2sin(t-k)\cos xdk$$

$$u(x,t)=\sin x \cos t+t+xt+\cos x[cos(t-k) \big|_{0}^{t}]$$

$$u(x,t)=\sin x \cos t+t+xt-\cos x+\cos x \cos t$$

Is it correct?

Comment: If you want to see if it is correct, first see if it satisfies the ICs and then differentiate and see if it satisfies the PDE.